# passing angular.js variables to html?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angular app in which there's a table that includes something of the general form:

```
<tr ng-repeat='d in data'>
<td>{{d.foo}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to use the value of `d.foo` (which, for example, could be `Bicycle` to turn the cell into a link to a website like `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle`. I've tried to find an answer to this on SO already but have had no luck; my apologie if I just didn't see it.

Is it possible to do the described task? If so, any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean : `<td><a ng-href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{d.foo}}">{{d.foo}}</a></td>` ?

Comment: Wow, yes, that's exactly it. Thanks a bunch, Cherniv.

Comment: Really? I've posted it like answer , if so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<td><a ng-href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{d.foo}}">{{d.foo}}</a></td>
```

You can read more here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref 
;)

Answer (score 2):

Use it in a `<a>` tag.
For example:

```
<a href="http://your_url/{{d.foo}}">{{d.foo}}</a>
```